# How to change .NET SDKs language in VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a solution for the problem like in title. When I have some errors .NET SDK displays them in my native language, but I want to see them in English, because it's much easier to googling English error messages

Comment: Most probably you have a Language Pack installed. Maybe you would be OK with uninstalling it, and that should make the error messages show up in English instead. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30667

Comment: I don't know which components is a language pack. https://i.imgur.com/yfdjy5a.png

Comment: @Leandro Uninstalled everything with .NET in the name, and installed again .NET Core, but it doesn't solved the problem. When on site, which you linked, I'll click Download then I have only HTML file with message "There is no English version of this language pack. To download a different language version, go back to the Microsoft Download Center page for this language pack."